# Convert two 16 Bit Registers to 32 Bit real value flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, modbus

I am using a Modbus flutter lib, reading 2 registers I obtain:

[22136, 4660]

This means: 0x12345678 I need a function to convert it to a 32 bit real value: 305419896, in easymodbustcp library I found:

```
/**
        * Convert two 16 Bit Registers to 32 Bit real value
        * @param        registers   16 Bit Registers
        * @return       32 bit real value
        */
    public static float ConvertRegistersToFloat(int[] registers) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        if (registers.length != 2)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input Array length invalid");
        int highRegister = registers[1];
        int lowRegister = registers[0];
        byte[] highRegisterBytes = toByteArray(highRegister);
        byte[] lowRegisterBytes = toByteArray(lowRegister);
        byte[] floatBytes = {
                                highRegisterBytes[1],
                                highRegisterBytes[0],
                                lowRegisterBytes[1],
                                lowRegisterBytes[0]
                            };
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(floatBytes).getFloat();
    }
```

Any help to do it in flutter / dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with bit shifts and a bitwise `or`. You need to shift the 2 higher bytes by 16 bits, then `or` it to get the value you want.

```dart
void main() {
  List<int> vals = [22136, 4660];
  
  int result = vals[1] << 16 | vals[0];
  print(result);//305419896
}
```

---

You could also achieve the same result in this case by replacing the bitwise `or` with addition.

```dart
void main() {
  List<int> vals = [22136, 4660];
  
  int result = (vals[1] << 16) + vals[0];
  print(result);//305419896
}
```

Comment: bitshits? I did not know those. Do they taste better than M&Ms?

Comment: @MarcosG. Oh sorry about that :). Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore thanks a lot... I have another conversions:
[21946, 17562] need to become a float 32bit -> 1234,6789
[50437, 12687, 19127, 16531] need to become a double -> 1234,67890000
Can please help me???? Thanks!

Comment: @Luca You need to describe the way that data is stored. The relationship between your input and expected output was clear for this question, you need to do the same for this new one. Ask a completely new question here on SO.